# MySQL AS как правильно прочитать данные

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с таким вопросов.

Создаю простой запрос с выбором данных из mysql

```
SELECT name, name2 FROM table
```

В результате вывожу

```
$row['name']
$row['name2']
```

После чего создается более сложный запрос со связями многие ко многим и приходится использовать уже такой вариант

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
...
```

И вот теперь вопрос! Если прописать таким образом вывод:

```
$row['t1.name']
$row['t2.name2']
```

Ничего не произойдет. И это понятно.

Возможно ли как-то ссылаться на таблицу а потом на ячейку для вывода? 
Или самое простое а может и единственное решение это также присвоить "сокращение" для ячеек

```
SELECT t1.name as name, t2.name2 as name2 FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
...

$row['name']
$row['name2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылки на таблицу вида `<имя_таблицы>.<имя_поля>` работают внутри запроса. Когда сформирован результат запроса, то столбцы в нём имеют только название поля. Таблицу-источник данных после формирования результата уже не определить. Поэтому указывайте имена запрашиваемых столбцов явно. `SELECT *` - это вообще плохая практика, если конечно известны поля, которые Вы хотите получить.
Вот только не пойму, зачем Вам alias-ы. Это:

```
SELECT t1.name as name, t2.name2 as name2 FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

и это:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name2 FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

даст одинаковый результат. Реальный смысл в псевдонимах появится, если в двух таблицах будет столбец с одинаковым именем. Например:

```
SELECT t1.name as name, t2.name as name2 FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: В примере я привел все верно не корректные названия и там использования не нужны. В моем же случае в запросах присутствуют три таблицы в которых существуют одинаковые поля. Но я вас услышал спасибо! Значит моя логика была правильной. И да * не использую некогда =)

Comment: Единственное что напрягает, длинна запроса из-за перечислений полей не повлияет на ее скорость обработки?

Comment: @Deniss `*` то же перечисление полей, только БД сама выбирает их из структуры таблицы, так что если ваше перечисление друг выберет не все поля, а только необходимые, то возможно это будет даже чуточку быстрее, правда там любая разница в скорости из этого исчезающе мала

Answer (score 0):

Не получится слишком просто. Либо каждое повторяющееся поле именовать AS, либо уникальные имена колонок необходимы.
Как вариант проверить запрос. Может подойдет для вашего случая UNION ALL (в мануал)